# Python Top Bigrams

Tags: python

```
import nltk
from nltk.collocations import *

tokens = ['a','b','c','d','b','c','a','b','c']
tokens2 = [['a','b','c','d'],['b','c','a','b','c']]
bigrams = nltk.bigrams(tokens)

fdist = nltk.FreqDist(bigrams)
for i,j in fdist.items():
    print i,j``

print fdist.most_common(2)
```

The code above works for input like tokens but it throws an error when I use tokens2. Eventually I am supposed to have it return the top 2 bigrams when given a set of tokens. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So `tokens2` is a list of list of tokens, right? Yet you say `sets` -- is that really what you want, or...?

Comment: yes you are correct that tokens2 is a list of a list of tokens. Both tokens and tokens2 are possible inputs in which I am supposed to return the top 2 most common bigrams

Comment: Having to accept completely different types of arguments, and acting differently on each, is an absolutely evil specification, as it requires type testing.  I would stand on principle and push back against that specification (I have taken such stands for many decades since back when I was in college, and despite some difficult consequences it has served my career, and whatever good I've been able to do in this world, extremely well).  I recommend you do the same, explaining **why** expecting you to accept both lists of strings and lists of lists is evil, absurd, and meaningless.

Comment: But if the blackguard spewing your specs is holding your baby child hostage, I guess you **could** check `type(toksofsomekind[0])` and change behavior accordingly (as long as you swear a blood oath to get back with equal cruelty to get revenge against said blackguard as soon as any chance appears!-).

Comment: You are correct Alex. It seems sadistic to expect the whole class to implement this kind of method that accepts a single list of tokens and a list of a list of tokens. I will honor your request and if needed I will engage my professor in fisticuffs.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of lists of tokens (like `token2`),

```
import collections
cnt = collections.Counter()

for toks in token2:
    cnt.update(nltk.bigrams(toks))

print(cnt.most_common(2))
```

would work.  If what you have is totally different, like a single list like `tokens`, or the `set`s you mention, everything might change - but we can't read your mind, so you'd better edit your Q to explain **exactly** what you're after!

Comment: The method is supposed to accept a single list like tok as well as a list of a list of tokens like tok2. From there return the top 2 most common bigrams.

Comment: @Datguyovrder, see my comments on your Q.  Since AFAIK you don't hold hostages against me, I'm not gonna stoop to type-checking to satisfy this evil, absurd, crazy, unjustifiable spec whereby you need to accept totally different types of arguments and act based on the arg's type (a spec which demands the horrors of type-checking).  If you can't convince your professor or TA or whoever set this crazy spec, please put them in touch with me and I'll do my best.